# Shell / Korn script - set variable depending on hostname in list

Tags: shell, sh, ksh

I need to write a korn script that depending on the host the script is running on, will set a deployment directory (so say 5 hosts deploy the software to directory one and five other hosts deploy to directory two).

How could I do this - I wanted to avoid an if condition for every host like below

```
IF [hostname = host1] then $INSTALL_DIR=Dir1
ELSE IF [hostname = host2] then $INSTALL_DIR=Dir1
```

and would prefer to have a list of say Directory1Hosts and Directory2Hosts which contains all the hosts valid for each directory, and then I would just check if the host the script is running on is in my Directory1Hosts or Directory2Hosts (so only two IF conditions instead of 10).

Thanks for your help - have been struggling to find how to do effectively a contains clause.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `case` statement:

```
case $hostname in
   host1) INSTALL_DIR=DIR1 ;;
   host2) INSTALL_DIR=DIR2 ;;
esac
```

or use an associative array

```
install_dirs=([host1]=DIR1 [host2]=DIR2)

...

INSTALL_DIR=${install_dirs[$hostname]}
```

Comment: `case` allows patterns like `host[0-5]) INST...`

Answer (score 0):

When you want to have configuration and code apart, you can make a config directory:  one file with hosts for each install dir.

```
# cat installdirs/Dir1
host1
host2
```

With these files your code can be

```
INSTALL_DIR=$(grep -Flx "${hostname}" installdirs/* | cut -d"/" -f2)
```